# Integrate distributed data source into a common platform

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, protege, protege4

I have 2 DB schemas which have mobile phone reviews. Single review has 3 elements. 
Review text, Rating and Category(This review is talking about which part of the mobile phone. Ex 'display').
I converted those into two RDF using D2RQ.

Now I want to build a knowledge graph for mobile phone domain. 
Ex : Display is divided into LCD and LED
How do I build such knowledge graph?

For an instance I can create following class structure using Protege.
[image]

am I doing it right? and do I need to create individuals of every sub feature in order to build the complete knowledge graph?

## -- Adding more requirements --

This is what I want to achieve.

Each review is classified to a particular category. It will be match with either super class or sub class. Ex : Display or Amoled

Using SPARQL I want to get all the reviews about super class, let's say about Display. Applying a filter on category I can get reviews about 'display'. But how do include reviews about sub classes like Amoled, OLED, LCD or IPS to the result set?

Comment: These questions are really too broad to answer here.  First of all, stick to one question - your second question about including comments should be its own StackOverflow question (and I reckon it's probably a good idea to wait until after you've got your knowledge graph bit done). Try editing your question to narrow it down: where, precisely, are you stuck when you attempt to build a knowledge graph?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I narrowed it down up to knowledge graph and that's where I'm stuck at the moment. Please take a look at the modified question. thanks

Comment: I cannot follow you. What is the SO-related question here? I don't think that people can judge about the "correctness" of the ontology that you modelled. Give 10 people the same task, you'll get 10 different ontologies for sure. If it fits your requirements, then it should be sufficient, right? You're the only person that knows what will be done with the ontology. Ontology engineering is a tough task.

Comment: Reviews are connected to instances of each class, so what is the problem. Right now you have just the class hierarchy, clearly, an object property `hasReview` and you're done.

Comment: SPARQL is graph pattern matching. it's pretty simple, just something like `select ?r {?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* :Display; :hasReview ?r}` - that's it

Comment: @AKSW the problem when the reviews are in separate RDF file where it only have the category name associated with. I want to link my ontology with reviews which are in separate RDF using sparql

Comment: Well, you how do you want to run SPARQL? I mean, what's the problem with loading all the data into the tripe store?

Comment: @AKSW I think that'd be my solution. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168895/discussion-between-eclayaz-and-aksw).

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right. And no, you do not need to create individuals of every subfeature. Unless, of course, the application that will consume this knowledge graph expects that.

What it comes down to is that to a very large degree, this is a matter of taste, and a matter of your own goals. From what I can judge your class structure looks fine. Whether it is "complete" or "good enough" is not something I can judge, because I don't know what you want to use it for.

Don't despair though: the good thing about using RDF technology is that you don't have to get it completely done or right on the first pass. Work with what you have, build your application, as soon as you hit a "I need additional info in my knowledge graph here" point, just go back and add it.

Comment: I have set of reviews which I converted to RDF. In each reviews triple is has a category which will be match with my ontology. Using sparql I want to find if this category which is associated with review is from which parent category. I'll add that requirement to question. Then it will be clear what I want to achieve